# Vue 3 computed not refreshing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to make a login form with Vue 3, but I have difficoulties with getting a state in 'realtime' or computed.
So when I try to login user from template it look like this.

```
<button class="login-button" type="button" @click="$store.dispatch('login', {email, password})">
  Sign In
</button>
```

And this button is working fine, it's sending data and making request to backend with vuex like so:

```
actions: {
        async login(commit: any, payload: any ) {
            API.post('/login', {
                email: payload.email,
                password: payload.password
            })
                .then((response) => (
                    localStorage.setItem('user', response.data.token)
                    )
                ).catch((e) => (
                    console.log(e.message)
                )
            )
        }
    },
```

As you see in actions, it's setting user data in localStorage, so in state, I defined user like:

```
state: {
        user: localStorage.getItem('user'),
    },
```

And it will set everything, untill now.
So now, when I try in navigation to get this state, it will not update it without refreshing a page. And I'm getting it like:

```
computed: {
    token() {
        return this.$store.state.user.user
    }
  },
```

Why should I refresh a page with this code? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: But I cannot see that you are actually commiting anything in your action `login`? Do really set `user.user` at this point?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set non-vue object.

```
app.mixin({
    data() {
        return {
            localStorage: {
                get(prop) {
                    return this[prop]
                },
                set(prop, val) {
                    window.localStorage.setItem(prop, val)
                    return this[prop] = val
                }
            }
        }
    },
    created() {
        window.localStorage.__proto__.get = prop => this.localStorage.get(prop)
        window.localStorage.__proto__.set = (prop, val) => this.localStorage.set(prop, val)
        window.localStorage.__proto__.get.apply(this)
        window.localStorage.__proto__.set.apply(this)
    }
})
```

---

```
localStorage.get('propName')
localStorage.set('propName', 'value')
```

---

```
state: {
    get user() {
        return localStorage.get('user')
    }
}
```